# How to move favorites in IDEA from one installed version to another?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have downloaded new RC3 of IntelliJ IDEA IDE, exported settings from previous version, imported to a new one, but I'm missing my Favorites for my project. Is there a way to easily move them to newly installed version? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Favorites are stored inside the project (`.idea/workspace.xml` file is used by default), see under `<component name="FavoritesManager">` node in the XML.

You don't need to move the Favorites manually, they are available automatically when you open the same project in the new IDEA version.

I've verified that it works by creating a new project in IDEA 11, adding a couple of project items to the favorites, then closed the project and opened it in IDEA 12. Exactly the same list of files and folders can be observed in the new version `Favorites` tool window.